# Tags [windows-media-foundation] and [mediafoundation]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

[windows-media-foundation](/questions/tagged/windows-media-foundation) has 45 questions, a tag wiki but no excerpt.

[mediafoundation](/questions/tagged/mediafoundation) has 21 questions and both a tag wiki and an excerpt.

(Ten of these questions have both tags.)

The actual product is Microsoft Media Foundation.

It seems to me that the tag should be named `media-foundation` or `microsoft-media-foundation`.

Comment: Working...  Please hold...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've removed both the [windows-media-foundation](/questions/tagged/windows-media-foundation) and the [mediafoundation](/questions/tagged/mediafoundation) tags and retagged all the questions that had them with the [ms-media-foundation](/questions/tagged/ms-media-foundation) tag.

I would have used [microsoft-media-foundation](/questions/tagged/microsoft-media-foundation) but it exceeds the 25 character limit.

I've also created the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ms-media-foundation/info) for [ms-media-foundation](/questions/tagged/ms-media-foundation).